# Creating a smooth spherical surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, 3d-printing, nurbs-surface

I am designing some parts for 3D printing and I have been banging my head for several days already trying to accomplish the following:

I have a "frame" that looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to create a surface inside the frame that has a nice organic, smooth spherical shape similar to the top shell of a computer mouse.

Here is a close illustration of what I am trying to get:
[image]

Unfortunately I am unable to achieve an acceptable result. I have tried curving a surface, using NURBS surface with modifiers, but still nothing.

What are the options for achieving this and having optimal control over the curved surface profile while it still clamps exactly to the "frame"?

UPDATE:
Here is my blender file with the frame that needs to have the surface along with a sample curve that I want for a profile for the surface.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want something round rather than sharp? Maybe share your initial file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is sculpting out of question?

Comment: I just updated my post with a link to the actual blender file, so you can get a better idea.

Comment: I need a smooth round surface along the curve meeting the frame edges, just like the top of a nice round computer mouse. I haven't tried sculpting yet, trying to stick to geometrical shapes.

Comment: do you a good reason for having so many vertices? Because you could give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier once your good with the general shape and it would make things much easier

Comment: @moonboots no particular reason. I am modelling the parts for 3d printing and dimensions matter, so it is easier for me to keep everything under control with more vertices. The frame shape is final and should not be modified further. I just can't get the smooth surface on top of it :)

Comment: I would say it's not easier to keep everything under control with more vertices, on the contrary, you should create your shape with much less vertices, then once you're glad, give it a Subsurf modifier and apply it. Here you could for example delete a lot of vertices of your basic shape then extrude up, etc...

Comment: actually it would be faster to restart from scratch, plus make sure that your object is made of one mesh because I'm not sure you can print if it is not

Comment: @moonboots I understand. I will try un-subdividing and manually constructing the curved surface in question and then sub-surfing. Hope to have better result. Thanks mate! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try extruding the shape, then use the bevel modifier with limit method to weight. By fine tuning the edge bevel weight in edit mode on the top edges you should be able to get something close to what you want.